# What is the definition of the pseudo spin of bilayer graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, material-science, graphene

The Hamiltonian for graphene at $\vec{k}$ away from the $K$ point is

$$
H=\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{k} =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & k_x - i k_y \\
k_x + i k_y & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
k \begin{pmatrix}
0 & e^{-i \theta} \\
e^{i \theta} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and eigen vectors are $(e^{-i \theta/2},\pm e^{i \theta/2})$. And we often call this vector pseudo spin (in terms of [the another quesiton](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144377/how-can-pseudospin-be-a-vector-graphene)). We can discuss the direction of the pesudospin (like [that question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30426/helicity-and-pseudospin-in-graphene) ).

How about bilayer graphene?
The eigenvectors of bilayer graphene are four-dimensional because four atoms are in the unit cell and the Hamiltonian of the bilayer graphene is four-dimensional. Can we define the eigenvectors of the bilayer graphene as a pseudospin and discuss the direction of the pseudospin of bilayer graphene?

I think the answer should be YES.
In [arXiv:1109.0307v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0307.pdf), they discuss the pseudospin of double-layer graphene. But I could not understand the definition of the pseudospin of double-layer graphene.